# Questions and Concerns About Using Java/Tomcat and Apache

Tags: java, apache, drupal, tomcat

I am having to use Java due to needing one backend library.

Is it still considered good practice to set up Apache as the front-facing server and have Tomcat behind it? I am spending a lot of time configuring mod_jk.

Also, what do people usually use for CMS or web-page templating in such a setup?  I wanted to use Drupal, but was advised that since I'd have to set up mod_jk and jump through extra hoops configuring it, it might not be a good approach.

Could you guys please suggest some common considerations or good approaches in this sort of a situation?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You might want to read about Tomcat's performance [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Performance_and_Monitoring)

Answer (score 1):

In the old days this was considered good practice, as TC was not as fast as httpd (especially for serving static content).

Today TC is as fast, so the reason would be rather to use httpd with mod_jk or [mod_cluster](http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster) (sort of a mod_jk++ with some auto-config features) for load balancing or fault tolerance.

Comment: Yeah I have been dealing with mod_jk but it is a pain to configure.  Is mod_cluster related to mod_jk or something separate? The reason I am asking is I am trying to figure out a sound approach of managing the UI layer in my Java application.

Comment: Mod_cluster is separate to work against some of the shortcomings of mod_jk - I've added a link to my answer.